# Consulta MYSQL rand() que muestre nombres aleatorios para una rifa sin repetirse

Tags: php, mysql

soy principiante en PHP y MYSQL pero tengo una tarea de crear un programa que haga un sorteo aleatorio, tengo un grupo de personas adultos que les tocará dar regalos, dichos nombres no los tengo en la base de datos, porque son estáticos, solo tengo los que están participando y quiero que a cada adulto en ese te caso le muestre un nombre aleatorio de la persona a la que le dará un regalo sin que se repita.

He realizado esta consulta con un bucle while.

```
    <?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM participante ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while($participante = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
  <h4><?php echo "A Erick le corresponde dar a: ".($participante['nombre']); ?></h4>
  <h4><?php echo "A Carolina le corresponde dar a: ".($participante['nombre']); ?></h4>
  <h4><?php echo "A Alex le corresponde dar a: ".($participante['nombre']); ?></h4>
<?php
endwhile;
?>
```

Lo que quiero lograr es que no me repita los nombres, al hacerlo de esa forma tanto a Erick, Carolina y alex le toco la misma persona.

Solo quiero saber como puedo mejorar mi código para lograr lo comentado o si existe una forma mas viable que pueda ayudarme.

He investigado y seguido tutoriales pero no he alcanzado el objetivo. Si ustedes pudieran ayudarme se los agradecería.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Les toca la misma persona porque haces limit 1. Eso solo devuelve un registro. Y en el while le asignas la misma persona a todos. Crea un arreglo de nombres: [Erick, Carolina, Alex] y úsalo para completar la frase dentro del while al mismo tiempo que se va recorriendo el resultset con los nombres de la base de datos.

```
<?php
    $nombres = array("Erick", "Carolina", "Alex");
    $i = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM participante ORDER BY RAND()";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    while($participante = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
      <h4><?php echo "A ".$nombres[$i++]." le corresponde dar a: ".($participante['nombre']); ?></h4>
    <?php
    endwhile;
    ?>
```

Comment: Excelente, me ha funcionado el orden aleatorio :), pero me da un Notice: Undefined offset: se da en la linea del h4 tienes alguna idea de por que?

Answer (score 0):

En tu sentencia sql te falta *GROUP BY* que sirve para agrupar los datos por nombres (para este caso):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM participante GROUP BY nombre ORDER BY RAND()";
```

Comment: Hola gracias por comentar, He aplicado el GROUP BY como indicas, pero el resultado es el mismo, si quito el LIMIT me muestra todos los nombres, pero a cada adulto siempre le tocan los mismos.